# ¿Como cargar items a un menú, a partir de una consulta ajax y que se adapte a la plantilla que se esta usando?

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Quiero hacer mi menu apartir de una consulta a la base de datos, para determinar que funciones tienen los perfiles de usuario, entonces realizo la consulta me retorna bien y agrega los items pero no me carga las opciones de niveles y subniveles del menu.

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
```

Ajax:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'tablero/menu',
    data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        'id_perfiles': <?php echo $id_perfiles; ?>
    }
});

request.done(function( data ) {
    $.each(data.menu, function( index, value ) {
        if(value.nombre=='Procesos'){
            $('.sidebar-nav #side-menu').append(''+
                '<li>'+
                '<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Procesos<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>'+
                '<ul class="nav nav-second-level">'+
                '<li>'+
                '<a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>'+
                '</li>'+
                '<li>'+ 
                '<a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>'+
                '</li>'+
                '</ul>'+
                '</li>');
        }
    });
});
```

Esto es lo que me crea, deberia de aparecer no desplegada, y al hacer clic desplegarlo, pero ademas de que aparece desplegada no hace nada al hacer clic en "procesos".

[image: Resultado del menú]

La plantilla que uso es esta: [Enlace](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html)

Aclaro que esto es una simple prueba para poder crear el menú completo.

Document.Ready

```html
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            var request = $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'tablero/menu',
                data: {
                    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                    'id_perfiles': <?php echo $id_perfiles; ?>
                },
                success: function(data) {
                }
            });
 
            request.done(function( msg ) {
                    $.each(msg.menu, function( index, value ) {
                        if(value.nombre=='Procesos'){
                            $('.sidebar-nav #side-menu').append(''+
                                '<li>'+
                                    '<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Procesos<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>'+
                                    '<ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">'+
                                        '<li>'+
                                        '<a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>'+
                                        '</li>'+
                                        '<li>'+ 
                                        '<a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>'+
                                        '</li>'+
                                    '</ul>'+
                                '</li>');
                        }
/*                        if(value.nombre=='Usuarios'){
                            $(".sidebar-nav ul").append('<li><a href="/usuarios"><i class="fa fa-slack"></i> Usuarios</a></li>');
                        }
                        if(value.nombre=='Perfiles'){
                            $(".sidebar-nav ul").append('<li><a href="/perfiles"><i class="fa fa-slack"></i> Perfiles</a></li>');
                        }
                        if(value.nombre=='Cargos'){
                            $(".sidebar-nav ul").append('<li><a href="/cargos"><i class="fa fa-slack"></i> Cargos</a></li>');
                        }*/
                    });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa este ejemplo, así lo implemente en mi página:

```js
var menus;
var todoMenus;
$(document).ready(function () {
    ObtenerSidebar();
 
 Contraer();
});

function Expandir(){
 $(".nav-stacked").css("display","block");
 $("#menu").css("display","block");
}

function Contraer(){
 $(".nav-stacked").css("display","none");
 $("#menu").css("display","block");
}

function ObtenerTodoMenu() {
  //Genero el menú de ejemplo aqui
  todoMenus = [
   {codigoMenu:1,codigoMenuPadre:0,icono:'fa fa-dashboard fa-fw',link:'#',lugar:1,menu:'Computo y Tablets',mostrarEnMenu:true},
   {codigoMenu:2,codigoMenuPadre:1,icono:'fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw',link:'#',lugar:1,menu:'Laptops',mostrarEnMenu:true},
   {codigoMenu:3,codigoMenuPadre:2,icono:'fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw',link:'#',lugar:1,menu:'Laptops',mostrarEnMenu:true},
   {codigoMenu:4,codigoMenuPadre:2,icono:'fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw',link:'#',lugar:2,menu:'Chromebooks',mostrarEnMenu:true},
   {codigoMenu:5,codigoMenuPadre:2,icono:'fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw',link:'#',lugar:3,menu:'Gaming laptops',mostrarEnMenu:true},
   {codigoMenu:6,codigoMenuPadre:2,icono:'fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw',link:'#',lugar:4,menu:'Desmontables y Touchscreen',mostrarEnMenu:true},
   {codigoMenu:7,codigoMenuPadre:1,icono:'fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw',link:'#',lugar:1,menu:'Tablets',mostrarEnMenu:true},
   {codigoMenu:8,codigoMenuPadre:7,icono:'fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw',link:'#',lugar:1,menu:'Lo mas vendidos',mostrarEnMenu:true},
   {codigoMenu:9,codigoMenuPadre:7,icono:'fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw',link:'#',lugar:2,menu:'Lanzamientos',mostrarEnMenu:true},
   {codigoMenu:10,codigoMenuPadre:7,icono:'fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw',link:'#',lugar:3,menu:'Convertibles 2 en 1',mostrarEnMenu:true},
   {codigoMenu:11,codigoMenuPadre:7,icono:'fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw',link:'#',lugar:4,menu:'Accesorios de tablet',mostrarEnMenu:true},
   {codigoMenu:12,codigoMenuPadre:1,icono:'fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw',link:'#',lugar:1,menu:'Computadoras de escritorio',mostrarEnMenu:true},
   ];
  
  
  /*  
  Este es el código para obtenerlo con ajax desde el server
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "Menus.aspx/ObtenerTodoMenu",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            var datos = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);

            if (!datos.Success) {
                alert(datos.Message);
                return;
            }
            todoMenus = datos.menus;
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(jQuery.parseJSON(request.responseText).Message);
        }
    });
  */
  
}

function ObtenerMenus(codigoMenu) {
    menus = [];
    $.each(todoMenus, function (i, v) {
        if (v.codigoMenuPadre == codigoMenu) {
            menus.push(v);
        }
    });
}


function GenerarMenus(codigoMenu, esSub) {
    var menuGenrado = '';
    if (esSub) {
        menuGenrado = '<ul class="nav nav-stacked">';
    }
    else {
        menuGenrado = '<ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="menu">';
    }

    //Obtengo los menus papas
    ObtenerMenus(codigoMenu);

    if (menus != undefined) {
        $.each(menus, function (i, v) {
            if (v.mostrarEnMenu) {
               
                var subMenu = GenerarMenus(v.codigoMenu, true);
                if (subMenu.length == 0) {
                    menuGenrado += '<li class=""><a href="' + v.link + '"><i class="' + v.icono + '"></i><span>' + v.menu + '</span></a>';
                } else {
                    menuGenrado += '<li class=""><a href="' + v.link + '" class="dropdown-collapse"><i class="' + v.icono + '"></i><span>' + v.menu + '</span><i class="icon-angle-down angle-down"></i></a>';
                    menuGenrado += subMenu;
                }
                menuGenrado += '</li>';
    
            }
        });
    }
    menuGenrado += '</ul>'

    if (menuGenrado == '<ul class="nav nav-stacked"></ul>' || menuGenrado == '<ul class="nav nav-stacked"></ul>') {
        menuGenrado = '';
    }

    return menuGenrado;
}

function ObtenerSidebar() {
    $(".icon-signout").parent().attr("href", "CerrarSession.aspx");

    var menu = "";

    //MENU NAVEGACION
    var sidenav = '<div class="navigation">';

    sidenav +=
          '<div class="search">' +
          '  <form action="search_results.html" method="get">' +
          '    <div class="search-wrapper">' +
          '      <input value="" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" name="q" type="text" />' +
          '      <button class="btn btn-link icon-search" name="button" type="submit"></button>' +
          '    </div>' +
          '  </form>' +
         ' </div>'

    ObtenerTodoMenu();
    var menuGenerado = GenerarMenus(0, false);
    sidenav += menuGenerado;

    sidenav += '</div><!-- End sidenav -->';
    menu += sidenav;
    //FIN ATAJOS
    $("#main-nav").append(menu);
   
}


/*
* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* main navigation toggling
* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var body, click_event, content, nav, nav_toggler;
    nav_toggler = $("header .toggle-nav");
    nav = $("#main-nav");
    content = $("#content");
    body = $("body");
    click_event = (jQuery.support.touch ? "tap" : "click");
    $("#main-nav .dropdown-collapse").on(click_event, function(e) {
      var link, list;
      e.preventDefault();
      link = $(this);
      list = link.parent().find("> ul");
      if (list.is(":visible")) {
        if (body.hasClass("main-nav-closed") && link.parents("li").length === 1) {
          false;
        } else {
          link.removeClass("in");
          list.slideUp(300, function() {
            return $(this).removeClass("in");
          });
        }
      } else {
        if (list.parents("ul.nav.nav-stacked").length === 1) {
          $(document).trigger("nav-open");
        }
        link.addClass("in");
        list.slideDown(300, function() {
          return $(this).addClass("in");
        });
      }
      return false;
    });
    if (jQuery.support.touch) {
      nav.on("swiperight", function(e) {
        return $(document).trigger("nav-open");
      });
      nav.on("swipeleft", function(e) {
        return $(document).trigger("nav-close");
      });
    }
    nav_toggler.on(click_event, function() {
      if (nav_open()) {
        $(document).trigger("nav-close");
      } else {
        $(document).trigger("nav-open");
      }
      return false;
    });
    $(document).bind("nav-close", function(event, params) {
      var nav_open;
      body.removeClass("main-nav-opened").addClass("main-nav-closed");
      return nav_open = false;
    });
    return $(document).bind("nav-open", function(event, params) {
      var nav_open;
      body.addClass("main-nav-opened").removeClass("main-nav-closed");
      return nav_open = true;
    });
  });

  this.nav_open = function() {
    return $("body").hasClass("main-nav-opened") || $("#main-nav").width() > 50;
  };
  
  
}).call(this);
```

```css
/*Pinto de amarillo los collapsables*/
.dropdown-collapse{
  background-color:yellow!Important;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="Expandir();" />
    <input type="button" value="-" onclick="Contraer();" />
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Titulo de la aplicacion</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">                  
     
                <!-- Menu generado -->
    
    <div id='main-nav-bg'></div>
    <nav id='main-nav'></nav>
    
                <!-- /.Menu generado -->
     
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper" style="min-height: 351px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Titulo de la pagina</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
    Contenido de la pagina
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="pruebamenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="pruebamenu.js"></script>

</body>
```

**Agregué el código para que se contraiga el menú:**

```
function Contraer(){
    $(".nav-stacked").css("display","none");
    $("#menu").css("display","block");
}
```

Para que funcione es necesario cambiar la siguiente linea:

```
if (esSub) {
    menuGenrado = '<ul class="nav nav-stacked">';
}
else {
    menuGenrado = '<ul class="nav nav-stacked">';
}
```

por esta otra:

```
if (esSub) {
  menuGenrado = '<ul class="nav nav-stacked">';
}
else {
   menuGenrado = '<ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="menu">';
}
```

Comment: Gracias amiga, me funciono. Como podría hacer para q aparezca todo agrupado? Con ese código el menú me aparece todoe expandido.

Comment: Listo @PabloContreras añadí las opciones para contraer y expandir el menú, saludos.

Comment: +1! excelente !

Comment: Grande grande. Solo le falta la separación de los subniveles y es perfecto este código. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Despues de implementar en un servidor local este template y probar tu codigo, me funciono perfecto SALVO por un detalle, yo lo estaba haciendo dentro de un

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.sidebar-nav #side-menu').append(''+
            '<li>'+
            '<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Procesos<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>'+
            '<ul class="nav nav-second-level">'+
            '<li>'+
            '<a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>'+
            '</li>'+
            '<li>'+ 
            '<a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>'+
            '</li>'+
            '</ul>'+
            '</li>');
});
```

Y esto fallaba, sin embargo, sacarlo de dicho evento, lo hizo funcionar de inmediato.

```js
$('.sidebar-nav #side-menu').append(''+
                    '<li>'+
                    '<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Procesos<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>'+
                    '<ul class="nav nav-second-level">'+
                    '<li>'+
                    '<a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>'+
                    '</li>'+
                    '<li>'+ 
                    '<a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>'+
                    '</li>'+
                    '</ul>'+
                    '</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
      <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
      <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
      <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
      <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/flot-tooltip/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/data/flot-data.js"></script>
      <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
      <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Navigation -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin v2.0</a>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-header -->
                <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

                <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
            </nav>
            <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

        </div>
```

Comment: en uno de mis intentos se la agregue, pero tampoco funciono, efectivamente recoge los items dentro del primer nivel pero no hace nada al intentar desplegarlo.

Comment: @PabloContreras donde estas cargando el ajax? dentro de un document ready?

Comment: si, yo lo cargo en un document.ready, sacarlo del evento no es la solución, para mi.

Comment: Por que no es una solucion @PabloContreras ?

Comment: Por que para ejecutar el codigo al cargar la ruta necesito q javascript lo ejecute al cargar la web, o me equivoco?

Comment: No, te va a funcionar igual... pruebalo!

Comment: no me funciona :-/

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50106/discussion-between-sioesi-and-pablo-contreras).